My dog hates the postman
Regardless if we are in the house or on a walk, my dog gets aggressive and reactive when we see the postman. I know it is said that our dogs are being territorial and associate the postman with something negative, but is there a way to stop this?

What is your specific problem? Is the dog "just" barking at the post man or physically attacking him? Or maybe attacking you? Dogs not liking post men is almost universal, but there is no universal solution to that. To give you a specific answer, we need these specific information from you. Please click [edit] to add more detail to your question.
